# Aggregation in data.table by reference to column names

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I would like to aggregate some columns by a **list** of columns in a data.table. However, I would like to refrain from using the column names outside the quotation marks (in the `by = .(desiredColumn1, desiredColumn2)`, that is). I am happy with using either the column names or the column indices. For example:

```
library(data.table)
x = as.data.table(iris)
x[, sum(Sepal.Width), by = .(Sepal.Length, Species)] # I want to avoid doing this
x[, sum("Sepal.Width"), by = .("Sepal.Length", "Species"), with = FALSE] # this does not work
x[, sum("Sepal.Width"), by = .(1, 5), with = FALSE]
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `c` with `names`

```
x[, sum(Sepal.Width), by = c(names(x)[c(1, 5)])]
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you for your answer. How can I also avoid referring to `Sepal.Length`?

For example:
`x[, sum("Sepal.Length"), by = c(names(x)[c(1, 5)]), with = FALSE]  # this fails`

Comment: @GerasimosPanagiotakopoulos  You are not referring to `Sepal.Length` directly.  Did you meant `Sepal.Width`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant `Sepal.Width`.

Comment: @GerasimosPanagiotakopoulos  You can either specify it in `.SDcols` or use `get` or `eval` i.e. `x[, sum(get(names(x)[2])), by = c(names(x)[c(1, 5)])]`

Comment: There is no need for `names(x)`. This works: `x[, sum(get("Sepal.Width")), by = c("Sepal.Length", "Species")]`

Comment: @djhurio It also works, but I think the OP wanted to pass the variables

Comment: He wanted to pass variable names as character vector.

Comment: @djhurio  I am not so sure.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to know how to do both, so thank you both! :)