# Apply an element-wise function to data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table and I would like to apply a function (e.g. paste, sum) to some of the columns. For example:

```
library(data.table)
x = as.data.table(iris)
columnsSelected = c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length")
x[, A := Sepal.Width + Sepal.Length] # this yields the desired result, but not in the way I want.
x[, A := sum(columnsSelected)] # this does not execute
x[, A := sum(get(columnsSelected))] # this does not yield the desired result
x[, A := sum(.SD), .SDcols = columnsSelected] # this does not yield the desired result
x[, A := do.call(sum, .SD), .SDcols = columnsSelected] # same as above
```

I am at a loss. `Get()` is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954534/aggregation-in-data-table-by-reference-to-column-names), but it doesn't seem to work for multiple columns. Another interesting discussion about uses of data.table is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790743/data-table-meta-programming), but `.SD` and `.SDcols` only seem to work for aggregations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you describe what your desired result is? It's not clear what you mean by "this yields the desired result, but not in the way I want"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an element wise plus, then just `+` instead of `sum` which sum all elements of the vectors together. Besides, since `+` accepts only two arguments, you can not use `do.call` with more than two columns, you will need `Reduce()` instead:

```
x[, A := Reduce("+", .SD), .SDcols = columnsSelected]

#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species   A
#   1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa 8.6
#   2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa 7.9
#   3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa 7.9
#   4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa 7.7
#   5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa 8.6
# ---                                                                
# 146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica 9.7
# 147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica 8.8
# 148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica 9.5
# 149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 9.6
# 150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica 8.9
```

As commented by @42, we see how `do.call()` and `Reduce()` work with functions as `+` and `paste()` by extending `columnsSelected` variable to three columns:

```
columnsSelected = c("Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length")
```

Where `do.call("+", ...)` gives an error as expected, since "+" is a binary operator and doesn't accept more than two arguments, while `do.call()` gives it three arguments (the three columns in the `columnsSelected`; `Reduce("+", ...)` works as expected since `Reduce()` add column by column instead of passing all columns to the function at once as `do.call` does. And for `paste`, `do.call()` and `Reduce()` both work since `paste()` can accept two or more vectors as arguments. And in this case `do.call()` is more efficient when you have a lot of columns but shouldn't matter here if you only pass in two or three columns.

```
x[, A := do.call(paste, .SD), .SDcols = columnsSelected]

#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species           A
#   1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa 3.5 5.1 1.4
#   2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa   3 4.9 1.4
#   3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa 3.2 4.7 1.3
#   4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa 3.1 4.6 1.5
#   5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa   3.6 5 1.4
# ---                                                                        
# 146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica   3 6.7 5.2
# 147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica   2.5 6.3 5
# 148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica   3 6.5 5.2
# 149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 3.4 6.2 5.4
# 150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica   3 5.9 5.1
```

And `x[, A := Reduce(paste, .SD), .SDcols = columnsSelected]` gives the same result as `do.call()`.

*Update*:
To pass parameters to the function in `do.call()` and `Reduce`, `do.call()` flattens arguments in the list parameter and take them as if they are individual, so in order to pass parameter to the function in `do.call()`, we can concatenate the named parameter to the list parameter, i.e:

```
x[, A := do.call(paste, c(sep = ",", .SD)), .SDcols = columnsSelected]

#      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species           A
#   1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa 3.5,5.1,1.4
#   2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa   3,4.9,1.4
#   3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa 3.2,4.7,1.3
#   4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa 3.1,4.6,1.5
#   5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa   3.6,5,1.4
# ---                                                                        
# 146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica   3,6.7,5.2
# 147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica   2.5,6.3,5
# 148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica   3,6.5,5.2
# 149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 3.4,6.2,5.4
# 150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica   3,5.9,5.1
```

For `Reduce()`, on the other hand, it allows you to reconstruct an anonymous  function, you can create a customized function with `sep` parameter specified:

```
x[, A := Reduce(function(x,y) paste(x,y,sep=","), .SD), .SDcols = columnsSelected]
```

Which gives the same result as `do.call()` again.

Comment: I wasn't sure this answered the question until I substituted `"paste"` for `"+"`. And also extended the argument to `.SDcols`.

Comment: @42 Right. Was trying to fix his code at the beginning. But the question is a little bit broad, when OP doesn't specify which function it is trying to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed reply! If I wanted to use `paste`, how could I pass an extra argument like `sep`?